# What can I do to fix this Syntax Error if I put everything in correctly?

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
def infPi(num):
    pi = 0
    for i in range(num):
      pi += (1/((2(i+1)-1)**2)

    print(pi*4)
```

The syntax error is for the line with "Print(pi*4)"

Comment: Count your parentheses. In general, if you can't find the error on the line mentioned in the error, look at the line before.

Comment: 2(i+1) is not valid syntax

Comment: The missing parenthesis is why the error shows up on the `print` line; the `print` is actually part of your `(1/((2(i+1)-1)**2)...` expression because you haven't closed the parens yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was a parenthesis missing at the end and a syntax error in the 4th line ( `pi += (1/(2*(i+1)-1)**2)` ) , try like this:

```
def infPi(num):
    pi = 0
    for i in range(num):
      pi += (1/(2*(i+1)-1)**2)

    print(pi*4)
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. Silly mistakes are the worst.